# UIImageView Covering Text in Cell

Tags: ios, text, uiimageview, cover

I have a UI Image View that is covering up text inside cells. How can I move the image to the background so the text is showing? Here is the code for the image.

```
    // image view
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[thisMovie objectForKey:@"poster_image"]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.jpg"]];
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this will work for you:

```
[cell.contentView sendSubviewToBack:cell.imageView];
```

Comment: Glad it helped! Don't forget to upvote and accept it in order to remove your question from the unanswered section